# How to search a dictionary with named tuple as key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, key-value

I wanted a data structure to have {(Document_name, term): (term count within document)} so I created dictionary with namedtuple as:

```
Doc_term = namedtuple("Doc_term", ["Doc", "term"])
Doc_term_count = {}
...
Doc_term_count[k] = {Doc_term(Doc_names[start_index + i], vocab[j]): row[j]}
k = k + 1
print Doc_term_count
```

It is giving me data structure as

```
    {0: {Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='be'): 1},
     1: {Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='script'): 1},
     2: {Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='this'): 1},
     3: {Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='is'): 1},
     4: {Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='there'): 1},
     5: {Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='wordcount'): 1},
     6: {Doc_term(Doc='book2.txt', term='hello'): 2},
     7: {Doc_term(Doc='book2.txt', term='to'): 1},
     8: {Doc_term(Doc='book2.txt', term='book'): 1},
     9: {Doc_term(Doc='book3.txt', term='read'): 1},
     10: {Doc_term(Doc='book3.txt', term='by'): 1},
     11: {Doc_term(Doc='book3.txt', term='first'): 1}}
```

I want to search in how many documents is the given term present with filter/search functionality similar to:

```
Dtn = filter( lambda ndoc: Doc_term.term=='be', Doc_term_count)
print Dtn
```

It is giving me null array. Please suggest me where am I going wrong. As per my understanding I am creating indexed array and filter lambda function is expecting list but when I try

```
Doc_term_count[(booknames[start_index + i], vocab[j])].append(row[j])
```

It is giving me error as : KeyError: ('book1.txt', 'be'). I think it did not accept tuple as key.

Comment: What data structure do you want? I think you don't want the leading 0-11, do you? You probably want `Doc_term_count[Doc_term(Doc_names[start_index + i], vocab[j])] = row[j]` That will give you a dictionary where the document name is mapped to the count.

Comment: yes I just want {Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='be'): 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're generating your `Doc_term_count` incorrectly - you just want your namedtuple mapped to the count. Without going into how you're figuring out Doc_names and row indices, I presume what you're trying to do is this:

```
Doc_term_count[Doc_term(Doc_names[start_index + i], vocab[j])] = row[j]
```

instead of

```
Doc_term_count[k] = {Doc_term(Doc_names[start_index + i], vocab[j]): row[j]}
```

The first approach should result in a dictionary that looks like the below:

```
Doc_term_count = {
    Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='be'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='script'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='this'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='is'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='there'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book1.txt', term='wordcount'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book2.txt', term='hello'): 2,
    Doc_term(Doc='book2.txt', term='to'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book2.txt', term='book'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book3.txt', term='read'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book3.txt', term='by'): 1,
    Doc_term(Doc='book3.txt', term='first'): 1
}
```

And then you can use your tuple to look up the values:

```
print Doc_term_count[('book1.txt', 'be')] # prints 1
```

Comment: I am not able to look up as suggested by you, it is still giving error as : KeyError: ('book1.txt', 'be')

Comment: @Manvi what's your current `Doc_term_count` after generating it with `Doc_term_count[Doc_term(Doc_names[start_index + i], vocab[j])] = row[j]`. Can you print it and post it in the question?

Comment: yes, It is printing Doc_term_count as you suggested. Actually I was using multithreading, some threads in which key was not present they were throwing this error. Otherwise it is correct solution. Thank you very much for your help.